# How do I gotoAndPlay on a button to a nested movie clip on a different frame on the timeline in Adobe Animate using easelJS?

Tags: easeljs, animate-cc

New to Stackoverflow and very grateful to everyone's input.
I have a button in Adobe Animate CC that I want to go to a different frame on the main timeline to a movie clip on that same frame. I can't for the life of me figure out how to reference the frame in the timeline in the function for EaselJS.

So if I have:

```js
this.back_btn.addEventListener("click", fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame.bind(this));

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame()
{
 ?????
}
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Are you just looking for a way to jump to another frame? Like `this.gotoAndStop(frameNumberOrLabel);`

Comment: So for example, I am on frame 10 and I want to have a button go to a nested movie clip within frame 3.

In my mind it would be, although I don't know the correct code

` this.frame3.movieclip.gotoAndStop("play"); `

Comment: Frames are not "containers" you can reference. You can go to the frame (which changes the state of the MovieClip to show what is in that frame), and then target the movieclip: `this.gotoAndStop(frameNameOrNumber); this.movieClip.gotoAndPlay("play");`

Comment: So, I may have violated some code rule here. I had another button on the same frame that also went to frame 3 (in this case). I removed that button and now it is referencing the movie clip within that frame.
It seems the other button's code was conflicting with the 2nd button that went to the same frame. I didn't think it would be a problem, but apparently it is.
I wanted a character list navigation with 5 characters in movie clips in one frame. When you click on that movie clip, it would go to the description page. From the description page, I wanted to go back to another character.

Comment: So it looked like this:
`this.back_btn.addEventlistener("click", fl_ClikeToGoToAndStopAtFrame.bind(this));
function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame()
{this.gotoAndStop(2);
}

this.character1_btn.addEventlistener("click", fl_ClikeToGoToAndStopAtFrame.bind(this));
function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame()
{this.gotoAndStop(2);
this.character1_mc.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
`
And wouldn't work. Where is the error?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing more. Any console errors? Can you add console logs in the functions to see what is happening?

Comment: Seems to be working now for both buttons. I changed one of the buttons to gotoAndPlay(3) and the other one to gotoAndStop(3) and it looks to have done the trick, although still confused to why you couldn't have both as gotoAndPlay.

To answer your question, I get the same default warning:
"WARNINGS:
Frame numbers in EaselJS start at 0 instead of 1. For example, this affects gotoAndStop and gotoAndPlay calls. (16)
Motion tweens are published as frame by frame animations. Use classic tweens where possible. (5)"

Comment: The lesson I learned from you, Lanny, is that you have to separate the statements within the function. That was helpful.
I added the console log, but I don't really know how to read it.

Comment: `lib.CYB300_The_SCOOP
BACK_BTN
:
lib.back_btn
CEO2_BTN
:
lib.BACK
CEO_BTN
:
lib.CEO_BTN
CEO_WELCOME_MC
:
lib.CEO_INTRO
PRESIDENT_BTN
:
lib.PRESIDENT_BTN

PRESIDENT_WELCOME_MC: lib.President_INTRO_MC
`

Comment: Note that those warnings in the Animate output just let you know what to expect when using certain features. They aren't errors in your code or anything.